# How to mock Gradle's buildConfigField for Travis CI build?

Tags: android, gradle, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I try to integrate my android app with a Travis CI. My app need an api key, that shouldn't be posted in repo. So, i put my api key in global gradle properties file `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`:

```
MY_SECRET_API_KEY="aaaabbbcccdddeeefff"
```

Then I read this value in `app/build.gradle` file (which is in public repository) and set it as buildconfig field:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    // ...

    buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", MY_SECRET_API_KEY
    }

    // ...
}
```

and use this api key in app code by accessing to `BuildConfig.API_KEY`.

I get following error message from Travic CI:
*Could not find property 'MY_SECRET_API_KEY' on com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated.*

Comment: so gradle.properties is on your local machine?

Comment: @RaGe, yes. `gradle.properties` is only on my local machine

Comment: travis is on a remote server right? it cant see your gradle.properties?

Comment: yes, exactly. travis ci is on a remote server and therefore has no `gradle.properties` file. That is my question, is there a way to configure gradle (or travis ci) to build my project without to publish `gradle.properties` in repository.

Comment: Did you manage to find out how to do this? Do you know if you can read a properties file based on flavour? e.g. read from the mock folder instead of the root. If you can that would work.

Comment: actually I think maybe that wouldn't work. maybe what RaGe said it the only solution.

Comment: @MichaelVescovo, yes, I use modified version of [this script](https://gist.github.com/KioKrofovitch/716e6a681acb33859d16)

Comment: I ended up doing the encrypt-file option for Travis but this is also nice if you want only fake keys uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Use Travis' environment variables; more specifically use encrypted variables so that the values of secure variables are always masked in the build output. You read Tavis env variables in the gradle script as `System.getenv('key')` though. It is cleaner to use environment variables on the local end as well. If you want to still use gradle.properties, you could do something like this:

```
hasProperty('secret_api_key') ? secret_api_key: System.getenv('secret_api_key')
```

To set Travis env variables, see [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Encrypted-Variables):
[image]